# How can choose number of nods in rpart?

Tags: r, tree, rpart

In `tree` package we can use following code for choosing number of terminal nods:

```
tree.model = tree(...)
tree.prune = prune.tree(tree.model, best = 20)
```

This code returns a new tree with 20 terminal nods.

In `rpart` package following code can use for this:

```
rpart.model = rpart(...)
rpart.prune = prune.rpart(rpart.model, cp =?)
```

That `cp` is cost complexity parameter. but I want similar `best` argument in `prune.tree`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rpart` package doesn't have a similar argument to `best` of `tree` package. The tree package was developed to cover the functionalities `rpart` was missing on.

To choose appropriate number of nodes, you can tune other parameters in `rpart`. For eg.

```
prune.control <- rpart.control(minsplit = 20, minbucket = round(minsplit/3), xval = 10)
rpart(formula, data, method, control = prune.control)
```

Then, evaluate the cross validated error vs cp, to choose a `cp` value. Also, you can automatically tune `cp` value using `caret` package. For eg.

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 5)

model <- train(x = train_data,
               y = labels,
               method = "rpart",
               trControl = ctrl)
```